# Creating a new array with smaller numbers within the array

Tags: c#

I need a visual algorithm.
problems: each element of the array will create a new array with elements that are smaller than itself in the array.
How can I do that?

[image: enter image]

I tried this method, but it was too slow.

```
int[] numbers = { 2, 3, 5, 6, 7 };
int[,] numbers2 = new int[numbers.Length, numbers.Length];
int number = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; ++i)
{
    number = numbers[i];
    for (int k = 0; k < numbers.Length; ++k)
    {
        if (numbers[k] < number)
        {
            Console.Write(numbers[k] + "-");
            numbers2[i, k] = numbers[k];
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: this is a one liner with linq, what have you tried?

Comment: I dont get why 7 should be mapped to  `[0,1,2,3,4]` and not `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]`

Comment: @InBetween I added the code I tried.

Comment: @mjwills it's been a very poor way of performing. looking for easier methods

Comment: You are not using [jagged array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays). Is your code working correctly?

Comment: Your code has different inputs than the question and does not produce the results from the question.

Comment: @KlausGütter each element of the array will create a new array with elements that are smaller than itself in the array.

Comment: `it's been a very poor way of performing` **Specifically** how slow is it?

Answer (score 4):

You could do it with Linq as follows:

```
int[] numbers = new int[]
{
    0, 2, 4, 7, 3, 1
};

var result = numbers
    .Select(x => numbers
        .Where(y => y < x)
        .OrderBy(y => y).ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

E.g. For each number, select the numbers which are smaller than said number and order by them. Since you want the result as arrays, use `ToArray()`.

Comment: This also solves the question what the actual question was and why 7 is mapped to `[0,1,2,3,4]` and not `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]`

Comment: Good job! The question wasn't clear enough but you got it right, I believe.

Comment: in c#, such methods(select,where, ordeyby ...) it's the first time I've seen it happen. Thank you!

Comment: @TolgaÇağlayan See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/working-with-linq

Answer (score 0):

With linq:

```
var output = numbers.Select(i => Enumerable.Range(0, i));   
Console.WriteLine(
    $"[{String.Join(",", output.Select(i => $"[{String.Join(",", i)}]"))}]");
```

Comment: Reading the question again and looking at the expected result, turns out kaffekopp is the one who got it right. `Enumerable.Range()` isn't the answer. OP just didn't do a good job explaining.

Comment: @41686d6564 ah ok, yeah, I understand now rereading his last comment 10 times.